# R htmlTreeParse() encoding UTF-8

Tags: xml, r, utf-8

I am trying to get the link list by following code

```
url.i<-"http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/duits/synoniemen/A/1.html"
doc<-htmlTreeParse(url.i,useInternal=TRUE,encoding="UTF-8")
xpathSApply(doc,"//a",xmlGetAttr,'href')[82]
```

Output:
    [1] "http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/duits/synoniemen/abbeiÃŸen"

But the problem in output is "abbeiÃŸen" but it should be "abbeißen" and i have already specified encoding.

Same problem appeared on following versions

Windows, R 64 bit-3.1.0 and and XML_3.98-1.1

Windows, R 64 bit-3.1.1 and and XML_3.98-1.1

Windows, R 32 bit-3.1.0 and and XML_3.98-1.1

Comment: I don't get the same result. It outputs `"http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/duits/synoniemen/abbeißen"` for me as expected. If you do `Encoding()` on that result what do you get? What OS, version of R  and version of `XML` are you using? Mac, R 3.1.0, and XML_3.98-1.1 here

Comment: Encoding() returns "unknown".

Comment: I can reproduce it on Windows - `Encoding()` is `unknown`, although it`s in fact `utf-8` (=> works if you set it manually). Strange ..

Comment: Thanks,i can move forward with this temporary solution as well.

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to only happen with `xmlGetAttr`. For example `xpathSApply(doc,"//a",xmlValue)[82]` seems to keep the proper encoding.

Comment: Exaclty, I am using that codeline in my script too but it gives proper output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that unfortunately `xmlGetAttr` doesn't support encoding like `xmlValue` does. but you can specify a converter to use with `xmlGetAttr`. Here's a function that will mark a character value as UTF-8

```
markUTF8 <- function(x) `Encoding<-`(x, "UTF-8")
```

then you could use it with

```
xpathSApply(doc,"//a",xmlGetAttr,'href', converter=markUTF8)[82]
# [1] "http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/duits/synoniemen/abbeißen"
```

Comment: Currently i am using the same but as the problem doesn't replicate itself on mac i was thinking that this is kind of a bug not the support issue.